# Automatically update PHP web application using GitHub

Tags: git, github

I have developed a web application, which I want to run on multiple machines all over the city. The application will run on local server (XAMPP). Is there any way to update the application on each system every time I push changes to my project on GitHub? Also note that I want these changes to be done automatically, without using git pull command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two easy Solutions to this:

1. Setup a cronjob, which automatically pulls every X minutes.
2. Have a webhook, which gets triggered, on every new change.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GitHub Actions](https://github.com/features/actions) to test and deploy your code every time you push or merge to your main branch.

I'm not giving you the whole explanation, as I don't know exactly what your setup is, but you could use SSH or [git-ftp](https://github.com/git-ftp/git-ftp) to tell the server to upload the new code to the given locations.